# AWS Api Gateway cannot rewrite path - 400 Bad Request error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-elb

I'm trying to set up an AWS API Gateway for something which was previously handled by an nginx reverse proxy. My endpoints are EC2 instances inside a VPC. I've already set it up so the gateway can access these instances.

The previous nginx setup looked like this:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location /host1/ {
            proxy_pass http://host1:8000/;
        }
        location /host2/ {
            proxy_pass http://host2:8070/;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The Problem arises when I try to rewrite the request path. I've set up a test route in the Gateway: `ANY /test/{proxy+}`, which I passed to the corresponding EC2 instance. I've verified, that requests pass through, but they contain the complete paths of the requests:

```
# machine 1:
curl -v 'https://<endpoint>.amazonaws.com/test/hello_world/test/a'
< HTTP/2 404 
< date: Sat, 18 Dec 2021 09:21:42 GMT
< content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< content-length: 469
< server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.7.10
< apigw-requestid: Kic2FiLIFiAEN_g=
< 
--- response ---
# server:
192.168.9.6 - - [18/Dec/2021 09:15:05] "GET /test/hello_world/test/a HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

(the 404 is expected, the important part is the request hitting the server)

I then tried to rewrite the request path to remove the leading `/test` using a parameter mapping: I specified "all incoming requests", Parameter to modify: `path`, Modification type: `overwrite`, Value: `$request.path.proxy` (the catch-all field defined in the route).

Now I get a 400 error, and the requests don't hit my server anymore:

```
# machine 1:
curl -v 'https://<endpoint>.amazonaws.com/test/hello_world/test/a'
< HTTP/2 400 
< date: Sat, 18 Dec 2021 09:19:53 GMT
< content-type: text/html
< content-length: 122
< server: awselb/2.0
< apigw-requestid: KiclDhxXFiAEMhg=
< 
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
# server:
-nothing-
```

**When I map the `$request.path.proxy` to `querystring.path`, instead of `path` the requests hit the server:**

```
# machine 1:
curl -v 'https://<endpoint>.amazonaws.com/test/hello_world/test/a'
< HTTP/2 404 
< date: Sat, 18 Dec 2021 09:21:42 GMT
< content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< content-length: 469
< server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.7.10
< apigw-requestid: Kic2FiLIFiAEN_g=
< 
--- response ---
# server:
192.168.9.6 - - [18/Dec/2021 09:21:42] "GET /test/hello_world/test/a?path=hello_world%2Ftest%2Fa HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

notice the value of the `path` query parameter is exactly the correct value which I would have wanted to replace the original requests path.

Is this a bug with AWS, or am I just missing some documentation, stating that you cannot rewrite path that way? Notably, when the `{proxy+}` path parameter is empty, requests get routed through correctly...

Answer (score 5):

The problem was with the value of the `path` rewrite: It should have been `/$request.path.proxy` instead of `$request.path.proxy`.